# Windows file share seems to change the network interface even though connecting via ip

Tags: windows, networking, file-sharing, smb, smb2

Between two windows servers I have a connection to the standard LAN (which is the default gateway) on the 10.0.0.0/24 network, I also have a direct connection between the two servers which is on its own network address segment of 192.168.50.0/24.

Server 1
NIC 1 (LAN): 10.0.0.1
NIC 2 (Direct): 192.168.50.1

Server 2
NIC 1 (LAN): 10.0.0.2
NIC 2 (Direct): 192.168.50.2

If for example I'm on server 2 and I browse to Server 1 in explorer \192.168.50.1\MyShare and then I proceed to copy a file from one server to another; instead of the traffic transiting across the 'Direct' NIC as I would have expected, it's transiting across the LAN connection instead.

I have tried numerous different things to resolve this, such as adding to the HOSTS file a record for each server on the direct IP and setting a static route via the direct, but nothing seems to work.

Is there something I'm missing as to why these file transfers are being redirected over the LAN connection instead of the direct connection?

Thanks
Anubis.

**UPDATE:**
Adding fully ipconfig and route print from each server.

**SERVER 1:**

```
>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SERVER1
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : {masked}
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : {masked}

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : {masked}
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AC-1F-6B-CF-FF-DA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter SXB1 QR2A Port 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-EC-EF-3D-3D-34
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Direct to Backup #1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-EC-EF-3D-3D-35
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.53.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Direct to SERVER2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-EC-EF-3D-3D-37
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::35a4:ed31:99a2:bedf%8(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 138210543
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-26-46-46-7E-AC-1F-6B-CF-FF-DC
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Direct to Backup #2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-EC-EF-3D-3D-36
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.54.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter LAN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AC-1F-6B-CF-FF-DC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1d65:d04d:6cc3:d240%7(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.6.52.207(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.6.52.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 95166315
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-26-46-46-7E-AC-1F-6B-CF-FF-DC
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter SW2-Pt1-0-3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AC-1F-6B-CF-FF-DB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.52.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter SW1-Pt2-0-3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AC-1F-6B-CF-FF-DD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.51.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled






>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 10...ac 1f 6b cf ff da ......Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection #3
  6...3c ec ef 3d 3d 34 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+
 16...3c ec ef 3d 3d 35 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ #2
  8...3c ec ef 3d 3d 37 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ #3
 18...3c ec ef 3d 3d 36 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ #4
  7...ac 1f 6b cf ff dc ......Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection
 15...ac 1f 6b cf ff db ......Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection #2
 19...ac 1f 6b cf ff dd ......Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection #4
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.207    281
        10.6.52.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.6.52.207    281
      10.6.52.207  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.6.52.207    281
      10.6.52.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.6.52.207    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.50.1    271
     192.168.50.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.50.1    271
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.50.1    271
     192.168.51.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.51.3    281
     192.168.51.3  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.51.3    281
   192.168.51.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.51.3    281
     192.168.52.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.52.4    281
     192.168.52.4  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.52.4    281
   192.168.52.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.52.4    281
     192.168.53.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.53.1    271
     192.168.53.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.53.1    271
   192.168.53.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.53.1    271
     192.168.54.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.54.1    271
     192.168.54.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.54.1    271
   192.168.54.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.54.1    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.53.1    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.54.1    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.50.1    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.52.4    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.6.52.207    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.51.3    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.53.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.54.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.50.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.52.4    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.6.52.207    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.51.3    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.6.52.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  8    271 fe80::/64                On-link
  7    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  7    281 fe80::1d65:d04d:6cc3:d240/128
                                    On-link
  8    271 fe80::35a4:ed31:99a2:bedf/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  8    271 ff00::/8                 On-link
  7    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

**SERVER 2:**

```
>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SERVER2
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : {masked}
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : {masked}

Ethernet adapter Direct to SERVER1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Mellanox ConnectX-3 Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-02-C9-22-9A-C1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter LAN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : QLogic BCM5709C Gigabit Ethernet (NDIS VBD Client) #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D0-67-E5-E7-85-EC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.6.52.200(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.6.52.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Legacy LAN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Mellanox ConnectX-3 Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-02-C9-22-9A-C0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.221.193(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{78E9D5F7-6C54-4CFF-8CCE-F0632DE0F538}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{EF745865-789C-47D6-A927-975965AD5EC1}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{FB99E3EB-46D1-48B0-8333-FC2CA589D211}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes



>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 27...00 02 c9 22 9a c1 ......Mellanox ConnectX-3 Ethernet Adapter #2
 15...d0 67 e5 e7 85 ec ......QLogic BCM5709C Gigabit Ethernet (NDIS VBD Client) #5
 24...00 02 c9 22 9a c0 ......Mellanox ConnectX-3 Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  5...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 26...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200    281
        10.6.52.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.6.52.200    281
      10.6.52.200  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.6.52.200    281
      10.6.52.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.6.52.200    281
       10.6.201.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     10.6.206.128  255.255.255.128        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       172.17.0.0      255.255.0.0   172.17.221.254   172.17.221.193     26
      172.17.51.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
      172.17.52.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
      172.17.53.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
      172.17.94.0    255.255.254.0        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
      172.17.96.0    255.255.254.0        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.17.105.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.162.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.17.163.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.17.163.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.163.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.169.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.17.170.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.17.170.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.170.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.170.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.17.171.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.17.171.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.171.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.171.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.17.172.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.17.172.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.172.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.172.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.17.174.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.174.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.17.174.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.17.175.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.17.181.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.17.191.32  255.255.255.240        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.17.221.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    172.17.221.193    281
   172.17.221.193  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.17.221.193    281
   172.17.221.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.17.221.193    281
       172.18.0.0      255.255.0.0   172.17.221.254   172.17.221.193     26
     172.18.32.16  255.255.255.240        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
      172.18.48.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.18.48.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.48.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.48.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
      172.18.49.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.18.80.64  255.255.255.240        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.98.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
      172.18.99.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.18.99.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.99.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.99.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.18.100.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.100.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.18.100.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.18.100.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.18.101.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.101.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.18.101.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.18.101.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.102.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.18.102.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.18.103.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.103.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.18.103.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.18.103.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     172.18.108.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
    172.18.193.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.18.193.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
   172.18.193.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1      10.6.52.200     26
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.50.2    271
     192.168.50.2  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.50.2    271
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.50.2    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.6.52.200    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    172.17.221.193    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.50.2    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.6.52.200    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.17.221.193    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.50.2    271
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
       172.17.0.0      255.255.0.0   172.17.221.254       1
       172.18.0.0      255.255.0.0   172.17.221.254       1
      172.17.51.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1       1
      172.17.52.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1       1
      172.17.53.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1       1
     172.17.105.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1       1
       10.6.201.0    255.255.255.0        10.6.52.1       1
     10.6.206.128  255.255.255.128        10.6.52.1       1
      172.17.96.0    255.255.254.0        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.102.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.18.102.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.18.103.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.103.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.18.103.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.18.103.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.193.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.18.193.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.18.193.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
      172.17.94.0    255.255.254.0        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.162.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.17.163.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.17.163.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.163.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.17.181.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.169.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.17.170.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.170.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.17.191.32  255.255.255.240        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.170.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.17.171.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.17.171.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.171.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.171.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.17.172.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.17.172.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.172.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.172.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.99.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.18.100.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.100.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.18.100.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.18.100.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
      172.18.99.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.18.99.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.99.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.98.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
      172.18.48.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.18.48.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.48.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.48.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
      172.18.49.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.18.80.64  255.255.255.240        10.6.52.1       1
     172.18.32.16  255.255.255.240        10.6.52.1       1
     172.17.170.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.6.52.1  Default
    172.17.174.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.174.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.17.174.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.17.175.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.18.101.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
    172.18.101.64  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.18.101.128  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
   172.18.101.192  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
     172.18.108.0  255.255.255.192        10.6.52.1       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IP addresses only, then you can ignore DNS/Hosts files.

I suspect this is the metric values for the relevant NICs, the below explains the values but you probably need to disable automatic metrics and set a smaller metric on the desired NIC.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299540/an-explanation-of-the-automatic-metric-feature-for-ipv4-routes

i.e.
'The Automatic Metric feature is configured independently for each network interface in the network. This feature is useful in situations where you have more than one network interface of the same speed, for example, when each network interface has been assigned a default gateway. In this situation, you may want to manually configure the metric on one network interface, and enable the Automatic Metric feature to configure the metric of the other network interface. This setup can enable you to control the network interface that is used first in the routing of IP traffic'

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have checked on the metric and the 'direct' connection is 15 whereas the LAN is 25.  This should preference the 15.  What is puzzling me however is even though I'm using IP, shouldn't it still be using the direct and not transiting across the LAN as there's no path to that particular destination IP via the LAN, only via direct.

Comment: Can you dumb a full ipconfig /all and a route print?

Comment: Sure, added to original question.